# how to determine how many mondays are between two dates

Tags: python-2.7, date, odoo-8

I'm developing an Odoo payroll module and I have a problem.

In Venezuela exists a salary rule named "Social Security" and its formula is:

(((Wage * 12) / 52) * 0.04) * mondays between dates

is there a way to calculate the quantity of mondays between two dates in Python27?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def num_mondays_between( start, end):

   num_weeks, remainder = divmod( (end-start).days, 7)

   if start.weekday() == 0:  # start is monday
       # one monday for each week between plus start
       return num_weeks + 1  
   elif ( 7 - start.weekday() ) <= remainder:
       # the closer start is to a monday, a smaller remainder has a monday
       return num_weeks + 1
   else:
       return num_weeks
```